# Java Dynamic Polymorphism and class file

Tags: java

I am trying to understand how dynamic polymorphism implemented. I have the following code

```
public class Bike {
 void run() {
   System.out.println("bike is running");
 }
}

public class Honda extends Bike{
 void run() {
   System.out.println("honda is running");
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   Bike b = new Honda();
   b.run(); // output 'honda is running'
 }
}
```

I tried to see the class file for Honda class and below is the bytecode for the main method

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: (0x0009) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=1
         0: new           #1                  // class newpackage/Honda
         3: dup
         4: invokespecial #31                 // Method "<init>":()V
         7: astore_1
         8: aload_1
         9: invokevirtual #32                 // Method newpackage/Bike.run:()V
        12: return
```

At line 9 there is invokevirtual #32 which is the 32nd position in the constant pool and it resolves to Bike.run. There is no #32 for the bike class as well as its constant pool only goes till #30
What happens at run time and how is run method of Honda class end up being invoked?

Answer (score 1):

The numbered arguments apply only within that particular class file, not across class files. As you identified, it resolves to `Bike.run`--at this point, the JVM goes to the `Bike` class and looks up its method named `run`.

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to understand it resolves to Bike.run so the output should be "bike is running". However the output is "honda is running" which means Honda.run was invoked. In class file we can see that Bike.run should be invoked according to the bytecode "9: invokevirtual #32"

Comment: @cloud That's what *`invokevirtual`* means--you're calling the `run` method declared by `Bike`, but if you override a method in a subclass, that's the one that's executed at runtime. That's the essence of polymorphism.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I understand polymorphism conceptually. I wanted to know what exactly jvm does when it reaches line 9 and how exactly the method is resolved. For example at line 8 aload_1 will load the reference variable b in the operand stack after that line 9 has to be executed and according to the bytecode it should invoke run method of bike class since that is at #32. What does jvm do internally to invoke run method on honda class. I dont think it changes the bytecode of line 9 at runtime.

Comment: @cloud You seem to be asking about *binding*, and the short answer is that it does some sort of lookup that combines (1) the type of the reference variable that's being invoked on and (2) the method signature. How exactly that happens is implementation-dependent, but it usually looks something like a C++ vtable, which may be a useful reference topic.

Comment: Yes I want to know how jvm decides at run time the method to invoke. The aload_1 loads the reference variable b and then invokevirtual is executed. Now if #32 just pointed out to the method signature I would assume that it combines this method signature and the type of the reference variable to call the appropriate method. However #32 resolves to Bike.run (#3.#33, #3 is Bike and #33 is run:()V). Any thoughts on this? I tried to find out more on this but didnt come across any good material.